# Array placeholders

Tags: arrays, placeholder

I’ve got an array where PLACEHOLDER is a placeholder for the variable $value that I get later in the code:

```
$names = array(
    "<a href='http://skyler.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Skyler</a>",
    "<a href='http://jesse.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Jesse</a>",
    "<a href='http://walter.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Walter</a>",
    "<a href='http://skyler.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Skyler</a>",
    "<a href='http://hank.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Hank</a>",
    "<a href='http://marie.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Marie</a>",
    "<a href='http://walter.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Walter</a>",
    "<a href='http://walter.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Walter</a>",
    "<a href='http://jesse.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Jesse</a>",
    );
```

To check how often an equal value is in my array, 
I count them with `array_count_values`.

```
$count = array_count_values($names);

foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . ' – ' . $key . '<br />';
}
```

So I get something like this:

```
3 – <a href='http:/walter.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Walter</a>
2 – <a href='http://jesse.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Jesse</a>
2 – <a href='http://skyler.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Skyler</a>
1 – <a href='http://hank.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Hank</a>  
1 – <a href='http://marie.com' title='PLACEHOLDER'>Marie</a>
```

Now I’d PLACEHOLDER be replaced by $value, so I get the number as title tag of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . ' – ' . str_replace('PLACEHOLDER', $value, $key) . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you asking, I don't understand, you want to replace PLACEHOLD with $value then do this

```
$names = array(
"<a href='http://skyler.com' title='".$PLACEHOLDER."'>Skyler</a>",
"<a href='http://jesse.com' title='".$PLACEHOLDER."'>Jesse</a>"
);
```

Comment: `$value` is an array I get later in my code, so if I write `$value` instead of PLACEHOLDER I only get a `2` in all title tags. But `$value` is actually an array that contains the following: `$value = array(3, 2, 2, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_replace` to replace PLACEHOLDER with `$value`

```
foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    $key = str_replace('PLACEHOLDER', $value, $key); //<--replace PLACEHOLDER here
    echo $value . ' – ' . $key . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct code is :

```
foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    echo str_replace('PLACEHOLDER', $value, $key); //this will replace placeholder with number of tags
    echo '<br />';
}
```